# Derivation of the Vlasov equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

Currently, I am trying to understand the Vlasov equation and how it can be derived from the many particle system.
It is not clear to me with which (physical) justification the "collision" term can be neglected.

One way to obtain the Vlasov equation is ensemble averaging:
The Klimontovich equation reads
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{F}}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot\frac{\partial\mathcal{F}}{\partial\vec{x}}+\vec{a}\cdot\frac{\partial\mathcal{F}}{\partial\vec{v}} = 0,\quad\mathcal{F}(\vec{x},\vec{v},t)=\sum_i{\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_i)\cdot\delta(\vec{v}-\vec{v}_i)}.
$$
Taking the ensemble average ($f=\langle\mathcal{F}\rangle$) results in
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec{x}}+\left\langle\vec{a}\cdot\frac{\partial\mathcal{F}}{\partial\vec{v}}\right\rangle = 0
$$
since $\vec{a}$ itself depends on $\mathcal{F}$.
With the definition of a new variable $C(f)$, we can write
$$
\left\langle\vec{a}\cdot\frac{\partial\mathcal{F}}{\partial\vec{v}}\right\rangle = \langle\vec{a}\rangle\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec{v}} - C(f)
$$
and thus we obtain the Vlasov equation (with "collisions")
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec{x}}+\langle\vec{a}\rangle\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec{v}} = C(f).
$$
Why can the term $C(f)$ be thought of as the collision term that can be neglected in many cases?
From this derivation alone, this assumption seems rather arbitrary to me.
The Vlasov equation can also be derived from the Liouville equation using the BBGKY hierachy.
However, we end up with the same issue where the integral on the right side needs to be split up in a convection and a collision term.

Comment: Think of a quasi-neutral plasma and only think about things above the Debye length.  On that scale, in the absence of external drivers and inhomogeneities, there is no net electric field and the plasma can be collisionless in low density situations.  Technically, the Vlasov equation is never truly correct but it is a valid approximation for many scenarios.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Maybe, I am looking for a mathematical explanation than a physical one. I don't understand why we can keep the convective term but ignore C(f).

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, it's just an assumption.